# Getting Exception when Safe-Casting to Generic Type in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, casting

I am using safe casting option in kotlin i.e. `as?` still i am getting class cast exception when the data types are not compatible, this is happening when I am doing this via a generic method written to perform case, however if I directly perform the cast it returns null as expected from a safe cast

```
class CastTest(val data: Any) {

   fun castViaGenericMethod(): TypeA? {
      return castToContext<TypeA>()
   }

   fun castDirectly(): TypeA? {
      return data as? TypeA
   }

   private fun <CONTEXT> castToContext(): CONTEXT? = data as? CONTEXT

}
```

`castViaGenericMethod()` -> this method throws `ClassCastException` when the data is not of the type `TypeA`.
`castDirectly()` -> this returns `null` when the cast is not possible.

Please suggest how can this be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your problem you could use a [`reified` type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters):

```
inline fun <reified CONTEXT> castToContext() = data as? CONTEXT
```

The reason, why it didn't work as you expect, is, that generic types are erased at runtime.

If we look at the byte code, we see that wherever your `CONTEXT`-generic type is written, it becomes `java/lang/Object`:

```
private final castToContext()Ljava/lang/Object;
 L0
  LINENUMBER 12 L0
    ALOAD 0
    GETFIELD CastTest.data : Ljava/lang/Object;
    DUP
    INSTANCEOF java/lang/Object // (1)
    IFNE L1                     // (1)
    POP          // (2)
    ACONST_NULL  // (2)
   L1
    ARETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this LCastTest; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

So the safe cast actually makes a check whether the given object is not of type `java/lang/Object` (1) and sets the value to be returned to `null` if that's the case. But as it is of type `java/lang/Object`, the value is just returned as is. On the calling side however the byte code looks as follows:

```
LINENUMBER 4 L0
ALOAD 0
INVOKESPECIAL CastTest.castToContext ()Ljava/lang/Object; // the call
CHECKCAST TypeA // the type check
ARETURN
```

It does an additional `CHECKCAST TypeA` after calling `castToContext` and there you get your `ClassCastException` as the value was not nullified (generic type information was erased at runtime).

Comment: Type erasure is exactly the reason why this doesn't work. The `castToContext` function doesn't have any access to the type used at the call site, so it doesn't perform any cast and simply returns the object. That's why the IDE reports an unchecked cast warning in the function.

Comment: Well that's stupid. Why don't Kotlin simply inlines safe-cast check on the calling site?